# Firebase Storage -File at URL: is not reachable. ensure file url is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a video in one location that I want to copy to another location but I keep getting an error

> File at URL:
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/...mp4?alt=media&token=...
> is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link,
> or invalid url.

```
let strFromFirstLocation = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/...mp4?alt=media&token=..." // this url is alive

guard let url = URL(string: strFromFirstLocation) else { return }

let secondLocationRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("copy").child(postId)

secondLocationRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
})
```

Comment: What happens if you try to get to that URL in your browser, or via Postman, or via wget (or curl) ?  Are you able to get to it okay?

Comment: @GregFenton hi, thanks for the help. Yes it works fine, I just c+p it in the browser and the video played

Answer (score 1):

I had to do 2 things to fix the issue:

1- I had to convert the first firebase url to `AVURLAsset` > `AVMutableComposition` > `AVAssetExportSession` and I used the `exporter.outputURL` to save instead.

```
let strFromFirstLocation = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/...mp4?alt=media&token=..."

guard let url = URL(string: strFromFirstLocation) else { return }
        
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

// ...

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

// ...

guard let exporterOutputURL = exporter.outputURL else { return }
```

2- I had  to add `.mp4` to the path as in `"\(postId).mp4"`:

```
let secondLocationRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("copy").child("\(postId).mp4")

secondLocationRef.putFile(from: exporterOutputURL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
})
```